# extend class-transformer Transform function to transform optional values if undefined

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator, class-transformer

Currently I use the `class-transformer` package to transform optional values to default values

```
@IsString()
@IsOptional()
@Transform((description: string) => description || '')
public description: string;
```

and two problems come up.

- I have to use this transformation logic multiple times for different types
- I want to make it testable for the code coverage report

So basically I want to create a function transforming the optional value to a default value, my current approach:

```
function transformValueIfUndefined<TValue>(value: TValue, fallbackValue: TValue): TValue {
  if (value === undefined) {
    return fallbackValue;
  }

  return value;
}
```

Now I could use this function in the `Transform` decorator

```
@Transform((description: string) => transformValueIfUndefined(description, ''))
```

but as you can see this is not worth the effort. Is there a way I can create my own transformation decorator alongside with `class-validator` and `class-transformer` to transform optional values?

My custom decorator should look like this

```
@TransformOptionalValueIfUndefined('')
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Decorators are just functions, so why not write your own? Something like this should be enough:

```js
function TransformValueIfUndefined() {
    return Transform((description: string) => description || '')
}
```

```js
@TransformValueIfUndefined()
public description: string;
```

Comment: Is there a way in class transformer? Without writing its own decorator?